# Cygwin "find" returns nothing

Tags: cygwin

This command returns nothing in Cygwin running on Windows Server 2008 r2:

/usr/bin/find /

I get a slight pause, but no text is returned. No error, no results, etc. I've tried with different search paths, using arguments (like -type f), and set my cygwin path to just /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin. Nothing works.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Well...If I tell you to "go find" something, what do you do?

Comment: If you think my syntax is wrong, tou clearly don't understand how the find command works.

Comment: The correct answer is: WHAT do you want me to find?

Comment: Okay user1147688, here's how find is supposed to work: When "find /" is called, it should dump a list of all objects in the file system.

Comment: Probably your `$PATH` is messed up or missing. What does `echo $PATH` give you? (And where did you set it?) Make sure it's set as a system variable and not a local user variable (in windows), but you can also override in `.bashrc`.

Comment: As I said in the question, path is set to /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin.

Answer (score 0):

That’s very strange behaviour and I’ve never come across anything like that while using Cygwin. I don’t have enough reputation points to ask for information using comments so I’ll just post the debugging techiques that I would use. Hopefully, they’ll be of use to anyone else who has similar issues.

Firstly, I’d try to verify that I was running the correct executable. Running `find --version` should return something like the following:

> find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
>
> Packaged by Cygwin (4.5.11-1)

If I still wasn’t getting any output, I’d (install and) use Cygwin’s `strace`
command:

```
mkdir testdir
strace -o find.out find testdir
rmdir testdir
```

`strace` allows you to see what calls a Cygwin executable makes to the Cygwin
DLL. With the above command, the output of the find command is stored in 
`find.out`.

Unless you’re familiar with Windows system programming, much of it
won’t make sense. However, looking through the output will still give you an
idea of what the command is doing, e.g., the Cygwin PATH and other environment
variables being passed to the command are captured. I usually search for `open(`
to see what files the command (find) is attempting to use. Successful calls to
the open function will be displayed like:

```
open: open(/home/anthony/t, 0x30C000)
open: open(., 0x400000)
```

Unsuccesful calls to open return a value of -1. Note that not all files that
find attempts to open are actually required for the command to operate correctly.
This is an example of one such unsuccesful attempt (the information in `locale.alias`
would be read if it existed but it’s not necessary for find to do its job):

```
open: -1 = open(/usr/local/share/locale/locale.alias, 0x8000), errno 2
```

Note: I create (and then remove) the empty `testdir` directory so there isn’t an overwhelming amount of information captured to the strace output file.

Comment: Thank you, strace is a good idea. I ended up wiping out the OS so I can't try your idea.